# How to parse a videoID that is in a callback URL query and use that videoID?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, html-parsing

For example,  when a video is uploaded to a video sharing platform, it returns a callback url - A URL to notify that a video is completely uploaded.

The [docs of the Video Indexer API](https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Upload-Video?), the callback URL made by the service will include the videoID in the query which I want to parse and use it in my own query string.

For example, if the callback url is 'https://test.com/notifyme?projectName=MyProject', the notification will be sent to 'https://test.com/notifyme?projectName=MyProject&id=12345abcde&state=Processed'.

I want to parse that `id` query string parameter, so that I can use it in my web page link:

What I tried to do was use substring and indexOf.

E.g: `var queryString = url.substring( url.indexOf('?') + 1 );`

But I am not sure if this is right approach, as I am not getting what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use :

```
var qs = url.split('=')[2].split('&')[0];
```

it will give you the id in this url
you can use split method to split a string into an array.

Comment: Thank you! this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use URLSearchParams

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

```
var paramsString = "<url here>";
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
var value = searchParams.get(key_here)
```

Comment: neat! Thanks for sharing that link.